# Wizards In asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net

I was trying to add a wizard type of look for the first run of my ASP.net application

How can I add wizards to my ASP.net application?

Comment: try to do it yourself ,then ask ,with some code snippet .

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of tutorials on this subject. A quick google gets these for example:

[Walkthrough](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/01/21/walkthrough-wizard-control-in-asp-net.aspx) and
[Using the control](http://v4.aspnettutorials.com/controls/using-the-wizard-control-with-asp-net-4-0-and-vb/)

Comment: ya but I dint get the exact search Friend. I got the search for how to create wizards in asp.net but I need is how to add wizards to my existing project.

Comment: "asp.net 4.0 wizard tutorial" did it for me. Were those tutorials what you were looking for?

Comment: I had Developed an web application Project now I want to add Wizard to it for the first run of my application.

Comment: i.e, when my Application got run for the fist time it should run with the wizard look

Comment: and for the second time it should look as it is now what I had

Comment: can I make it? Is that possible?

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a wizard (from the tutorial) to a page of it's own, like start.aspx. then once it's ran you can, by way of code, set a setting in the web.config to say the wizard has ran. This setting can be checked when the site loads in the future - if it hasn't been set then run the wizard. Other than that, you'll need to do some leg work yourself. I've helped as much as the scope of your question allows :)

Comment: Thank You Dareen but how can I add wizads to my application

Comment: If you have indeed built your own application you should know how to follow a simple tutorial.. perhaps you should sit and follow those tutorials then you will be better equipped to ask more serious questions. Sorry, I have given all the help I can at this stage. I believe I answered your question and then a little more :)